# Prove that if $9\mid(x^3 + y^3 + z^3)$ then $3\mid xyz$ for integers $x, y, z$

Tags: congruences

how would I prove that if 9 divides $x^3+y^3+z^3$ then $3$ divides $xyz$?

I've thought about it and don't really know where to start. So far, I know that $x^3+y^3+z^3$ is congruent to $0 (\mod 9)$.

I don't know where to go from here.

Comment: WHY does it only work for consecutive integers? The answer to that may supply a clue to the proof.

Comment: It need not only work for consecutive integers. For example take $x=3, y=6, z=12$.

Comment: @AnuragA Thank you,that's why it sounded fishy to me without a proof of that statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that for any integer $a$ we have  $a^3 \equiv 0, \pm 1 \pmod{9}$. So for $x^3+y^3+z^3 \equiv 0 \pmod{9}$ we can only have the following scenarios:

1. Each of $x^3, y^3$ and $z^3$ are $0 \bmod{9}$.
2. One of them is $0 \bmod{9}$ and the remaining two are $1 \bmod{9}$ and $-1 \bmod{9}$.

But in both cases we have at least one (say) $x^3 \equiv 0 \pmod{9}$. This implies $x^3 \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$. Consequently $x \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$. This implies $xyz \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$.

Comment: How would you prove that  $a^3 \equiv 0, \pm 1 \pmod{9}$ for every n?Without proving this first, you're whole approach is suspect. I'd assume induction.

Comment: No need of induction. Any integer when divided by $9$ will leave a remainder from the set $\{0,1,2, \ldots ,8\}$. Thus when we compute $x^3 \bmod{9}$ the residues will be among $\{0^3,1^3,2^3, \ldots ,8^3\}$. Now modulo $9$ this set has only three distinct elements $\{0,1,-1\}$.

Comment: Very nice common sense proof! I gotta review my number theory. Melvyn Nathanson would have made a clown out of me for asking that question in class.......lol